# Need help understanding how loop a function

Tags: php, function

I'm creating a function that passes a URL over and gets the content of the page. If this page contains "Next>", I would like to grab the url of that and continue onto the page next under the page doesn't contain next anymore.

How would this be done? a while loop?

```
check_url("http://site.com");
-> url contains 'next', href is http://site.com/ggkdoe

-> does http://site.com/ggkdoe contain next? if so, hit it again and check if that contains 'next' then get that url etc etc
```

Understand? How can this be done?

Thank you in advance

Comment: normally, "Next" button is generated by server-side, not parsing client-side output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

Comment: I can get the URLs fine, I just need to keep continuing on until the term doesn't exist on the page anymore. I'm using Simple HTML Dom

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something like this:

```
<?php
$checkNext = false;
$currentURL = "http://site.com";
do {
    $check = check_url($currentURL);
    if ($check !== null) {
       $currentURL = $check;
       $checkNext = true;
    } else {
       $checkNext = false;
    }
} while ($checkNext);
```

And I assume that `check_url()` will return an URL if one could be found and `null` otherwise. The `do`-`while`-loop ensures that the check is done at least once for the initial URL and afterwards again as long as `check_url()` could find another URL. At the end use `$currentURL` for whatever you want to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursivity for complete link search:

```
function checkUrl($url) {
    $atLeastOneUrl = true;
    // Check your content
    // Log some data about current Url
    foreach ($urlFound in $urlsFound){
        check_url($urlFound);
        $atLeastOneUrl=true;
    }

return $atLeastOneUrl;
}
```

But you will want to check that link 1 --> link 2 --> ... --> link1 cycle won't interfer with your search ;)